# Access to the Elementor widget category list

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I tried to use elementor widget categories list in my plugin.
I used the following code:

```
add_action('elementor/elements/categories_registered', function($manager) {
    global $elementor_categories;
    $elementor_categories = $manager->get_categories();
});
```

The problem with this method is that the action is not called on my plugin page.

Is there a way to directly access the elementor widget categories list?

Comment: This action doesn't make much sense to use. This action is to add custom widget categories to Elementor. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am making a plugin where it is possible to change the categories of elementor widgets. Before I need to display the list of registered categories.

Comment: Update your question with the information of your comment. Your comment should be the question - since that makes more sense to what you're trying to do.